# itemizing items in list based on example given on a tutorial

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I am having following entries

```
\begin{itemize}
     \item[\renewcommand{labelitem}{$\cdot}] To be able to understand the anomaly detection techniques by existing service providers.
     \item[\textendash\textbf{ii}] To be able to implement an approach which can detect anomalies in a given data set.\\
\end{itemize}
```

I read an example here http://texblog.org/2008/10/16/lists-enumerate-itemize-description-and-how-to-change-them/ 
which says Itemization is probably the mostly used list in Latex. It also provides four levels. The bullets can be changed for each level using the following command:

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\cdot$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\diamond$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$\ast$}
```

I want to know in my usage of \renewcommand as I did above since I am getting a lot of errors.
So obviously it is wrong but what should a correct format look like. I want to use the `{$\cdot$}`
in my attempt. I do not know how to do so. I tried in above way but I got a lot of errors.
I am using a template given to us which I have uploaded [here](https://github.com/kiotie32/original-template).If any one wants to have a look.
I am learning latex so I am not very clear where to put \renewcommand statements or use \itemize.
I do have prepared an incomplete document of 35 pages by this kind of hit and trial.
I read examples given here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures. The third last example

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\ListProperties(Hide=100, Hang=true, Progressive=3ex, Style*=-- ,
Style2*=$\bullet$ ,Style3*=$\circ$ ,Style4*=\tiny$\blacksquare$ )
% ...

\begin{easylist}
& Blah
& Blah
&& Blah
&&& Blah
&&&& Blah
&&&&& Blah
\end{easylist}
```

how ever what I want to achieve is a few items with only circles in points as items.
Not using this template is not an option for me.
*update 1*
based on a comment below I tried

```
\begin{itemize}
     \item[\renewcommand{labelitem}{$\cdot$}] To be able to understand the anomaly detection techniques by existing service providers.
     \item[\renewcommand{labelitem}{$\cdot$}] To be able to implement an approach which can detect anomalies in a given data set.\\
\end{itemize}
```

but this gave me error

```
Command labelitem undefined. \item[\renewcommand{labelitem}{$\cdot$}]

Missing control sequence inserted. \item[\renewcommand{labelitem}{$\cdot$}]
```

also I have 2 warnings

```
\fancyhead's `E' option without twoside option is useless
```

and

```
fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015(fixltx2e) All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
```

I want to know where to remove and what should be removed to get rid of these warnings? This is the template https://github.com/kiotie32/original-template if any one want to see. I am not sure what to do to get rid of these warnings also.

Comment: In `\item[\renewcommand{labelitem}{$\cdot}] ` there is a "closing" `$` missing and a `\ ` in front of `labelitem`. Yet I would suggest to use `enumitem`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat ok I tried   `\begin{itemize}
     \item[\renewcommand{labelitem}{$\cdot$}] To be able to understand the anomaly detection techniques by existing service providers.
     \item[\renewcommand{labelitem}{$\cdot$}] To be able to implement an approach which can detect anomalies in a given data set.\\
\end{itemize}`     but now I get error   `Command labelitem undefined. \item[\renewcommand{labelitem}{$\cdot$}]`

Comment: Your posting looks like is deals with two separate and almost entirely independent topics. The first topic seams about modifying the symbols used in `itemize`-like lists. The second topic is, AFAICT, related to the `easylist` package. This site doesn't work well if queries contain separate and more or less unrelated issues. Please advise what the focus of your query is. If you have more than one question, please post more than one query.

Comment: I wanted to know how can I change the dashes to dots to circles in itemize. The answer you gave I tried and it worked well. I tried a few more combinations also since you mentioned that blog is out dated I did not go with what I was trying by reading things from blog. I do not know any thing about `easylist` package I heard it first time and I have been trying various examples I got on internet. Thinking that they may change how items in \itemize appear.

Comment: My last attempt to help you to get better help: Please provide a code in your questions, that can be compiled without further modification: MWE. Starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document}. This has nothing to do with your Latex skill level. This is just common sense to make it easier for others to run your code. If this comment does not help as did my others comments, then I will just give up :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I will keep your suggestion in mind. Actually being new to Latex world I was not even able to understand what is `\documentclass` and why is it used. I though wrote a paper and some report using latex. So here in 2-3 days I got time to read through many tutorials I tried them. So now I understand a little bit what is 
`\ documentclass`.So when you previously said to use all this I could not understand any thing.Secondly some times I try things on a template EUSFLAT2019 which was available on overleaf for free.I read each and every line of the template.I will do the needful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog you refer to is quite dated. Over the past 10+ years, the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/) package has become, dare I say it, *the* main package for modifying and customizing list-like environments such as `enumerate` and `itemize`. I suggest you avail yourself of the package's many capabilities.

The following MWE shows you how to get started. Incidentally, I would not use `\cdot` to mark level-2 itemized objects; the `\cdot` symbol just isn't big enough to serve reliably as a marker of this type. I would use `\circ` rather than `\cdot`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=$\circ$}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=$\diamond$}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=$\ast$}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Hello
\begin{itemize}
\item Level 1
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Level 2
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Level 3
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Level 4
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great this is what I was looking for. I want to know that this method you used will it apply to all the items on different different chapters if I itemize them.I mean to say my understanding is that any thing written before `\begin{document}` applies to all the things in document.Also you mention the blog is dated I am a bit not clear to understand this you meant to say that the blog is obsolete and I should check some other tutorial.

Comment: @koeradoera - When I wrote that the blog is dated, I meant that it was clearly written before the `enumitem` was created. If anybody were to write a tutorial today about how one might customize LaTeX's list-like environments but didn't give much prominence to the `enumitem` package, I wouldn't say that they'd be doing their readers a favor.

Comment: @koeradoera - Indeed, if the `\setlist` instructions occur in the preamble, their scope is *global*, i.e., it pertains to the entire document.